# C# Access form-object from thread(other class)? Multithreaded object array needed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, delegates

> **[OT-Intro]**
>
> *I am actually C coder and just started today with C# for the only reason that there is a library existing for that really simplifies my
>   life. I am sorry that my knowledge is really weak and I have to admit that I am more interested in finishing this tool than interested in learning a new programming language. I hope you will still help me to solve the issue plus explain me my second question. Thanks!*
>
> **[/OT-Intro]**

However, I need to access/update a **form object => RichTextBox(.AppendText)** from a **thread (safely) in my multithreaded application**.

More specific, I want programmatically do the follow:

```
component.OnEvent += delegate(object o) 
{ 
    lock (lockObj) 
    { 
        FormMain.RichTextBox.AppendText("SomeRandomText")
    }; 
};
```

In case I understand everything right, lock(lockObj) would block the access to RichTextBox, **so this should be saflely updated**?

However, I don't know how to access the RichTextBox (*appreciate the easiest if not too slow*) way.

**And the second question - Multithreaded object array needed?**

At the moment I just create one single object like that:

```
ThreadClass threadclassobj = new ThreadClass ();
```

And call it for example this way (ofc not this way):

```
for (;;)
{
    threadclassobj.StartTheThread(username, password);     
}
```

StartTheThread looks like this:

```
public Thread StartTheThread(string param1, string param2)
{
    var t = new Thread(() => Check(param1, param2));
    t.Start();
    return t;
}
```

I used the Lamda-expression method to pass the arguments..

I am just curious how this gets handled, I wonder how one object creates multiple Threads at the same time and work the parameters in the right way.

Normally(in C) i would create an array of ThreadClass.

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, lock(object) does not "lock" the object as you would expect. I'm pretty sure that you must make sure you are implementing lock(object) anywhere else you are using it, as basically lock just keeps track of what is using and and says "you may have it" when nothing else is. If you don't use lock, you can still edit the object, its just not asking permission first.

Comment: Also, I'm not completely clear on what exactly your second question is, but would it work to just create a List<ThreadClass> ?

Comment: Is `FormMain` the classname of your form, or a reference to an instantiated form? You should have a handle to an existing form, and the `RichTextBox` should be `public` for you to be able to edit it's properties.

Comment: Hey bkribbs, my question is actually if I need to do it or not and if not - why?. The code got (I think) executed the right way and all the different passed parameters got processed properly - and I don't know why.

Comment: Well let me see if this answers your question: when you have `var t = new Thread(() => Check(param1, param2));` The parameter in Thread() is "A System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart delegate that represents the methods to be invoked when this thread begins executing." So that lambda expression is being executed on another thread already. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @bkribbs To be honest - no. I explain why: When I create a new object `(ThreadClass)` and I create a new Thread with it and pass 2 parameters, and then I create the next Thread immediatly and assign it to `the same object`, then should all static variables of the object which hold the parameters get overwritten. So the data should at least not get processed the right way - but apparently everything is fine and that's what i don't understand. My english understanding is not that well, maybe I just don't understand what you tried to explain me and your explanatation is just right.Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem, I'm not super familiar with lambda expressions so that could be part of the problem. When you say it is assigned to the same instance of an object, which object are you saying is the same? And you are saying that that object has some static variables in it that you believe should be overwritten but are not?

Answer (score 0):

To access/write to a winforms object, you don't need a lock, you need Invoke:

```
FormMain.Invoke((Action) delegate {
    FormMain.RichTextBox.AppendText("SomeRandomText")
});
```

This is thread-safe.

For your second question, you're throwing away the reference to the thread, so you won't be able to get the result to them. If you need to get the result, then yes, you would need a `List<Thread>` to store them in.

If you are using the latest .Net (4.0 and above) you may want to look at the Task Parallel Library. It greatly simplifies multithreading for C#:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    //Multithreaded stuff here
    return obj;
});
// Sometime later...
var result = task.result;
```